# Arc doesn't shows on wpf canvas?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, draw

I'm going to make an application which can draw an arc from a (X1,Y1) point to (X2,Y2).

(X1,X2) is the first point I click on the canvas, and (X2,Y2) is the second click after the first one. When the first click occur, the first arc point (X1,Y1) is saved, and the second arc point is relative to the mouse pointer, so this way, I can flexibly make the canvas width, WHILE THERE'S A "GHOST" ARC TO VISUALLY SHOWS THE USER HOW THE ARC WILL BE MADE BEFORE THEY FINALLY DECIDED THE SECOND CLICK (doesn't need to hold the click).

> A "GHOST" is when on, let say, power point, you insert a line, you
>   hold the first click, and then move your mouse around, the end point
>   on the line looks like it connected to the mouse pointer until the
>   left click released. It's visually like a line, but until you release your click
>   the line isn't "drawn" and still can be flexibly adjusted.

However, the Y2, IS ALWAYS EQUAL TO Y1, so that's mean, that the arc always on the same Y at both side.

This is my XAML :

```
<Window x:Class="Drawing.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Height="25" IsEnabled="False" Name="txt" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Width="100"/>
    <Canvas Name="cnv" MouseLeftButtonDown="cnv_MouseLeftButtonDown" Background="Transparent" Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1" MouseMove="cnv_MouseMove"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

And this is my MainWindow class :

```
    Ellipse ellipse = null;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void cnv_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Point p = Mouse.GetPosition(cnv);

        txt.Text = p.ToString();

        if (ellipse == null)
        {
            Point first = p;
            ellipse = new Ellipse();
            ellipse.Fill = Brushes.Transparent;
            ellipse.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
            ellipse.StrokeThickness = 1;

            Canvas.SetTop(cnv, p.Y);
            Canvas.SetLeft(cnv, p.X);
            ellipse.Width = p.X - Canvas.GetLeft(ellipse);
            ellipse.Height = 20;
            ellipse.Clip = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, ellipse.Height / 2, ellipse.Width, ellipse.Height));

            cnv.Children.Add(ellipse);
        }
        else
        {
            ellipse = null;
        }
    }

    private void cnv_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point p = Mouse.GetPosition(cnv);

        txt.Text = p.ToString();

        if (ellipse != null)
        {
            ellipse.Width = p.X - Canvas.GetLeft(ellipse);
            ellipse.Height = 20;
            ellipse.Clip = new RectangleGeometry(new Rect(0, ellipse.Height / 2, ellipse.Width, ellipse.Height));
        }
    }
```

Any idea how to solve this?

P.S. I'm not strictly on clipped ellipse, if you can show me another way to do it, it's fine. However, I insist on doing this on codebehind not on the XAML.

P.S.S. My arc can't be edited after the second click occur, it can only be deleted.

P.S.S.S. Before I drew arc, I was drawing a line by the same method and it's works fine. The difference is on the line have X1,Y2,X2,Y2 while the ellipse doesn't (I think this where the problem is, but I can't figure how to fix it. Maybe I was wrong)

P.S.S.S.S. Additional weirdness : There's a blink of a black line on the top-left side of my canvas when the first click occur, but when I move my mouse, the line is vanished. I wonder what that was.

Thanks

Comment: +1 for a properly detailed, well formatted question with all the relevant code.

Comment: Thanks. Any solution or some point of view on the topic that may help the problem-solving? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `Canvas.Left` and `Canvas.Top` on the Ellipse, not on the Canvas.

in `cnv_MouseLeftButtonDown` change

```
Canvas.SetTop(cnv, p.Y);
Canvas.SetLeft(cnv, p.X);
```

to

```
Canvas.SetTop(ellipse, p.Y);
Canvas.SetLeft(ellipse, p.X);
```

Another bug is `cnv_MouseMove`, where the expression

```
ellipse.Width = p.X - Canvas.GetLeft(ellipse);
```

tries to assign a negative width to the Ellipse when the mouse pointer moves left beyond the start point.

Comment: wow I can't believe I was wrongly set the canvas, instead of ellipse. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure I understand how you're trying to specify your arc, but I drew an arc for my program (more like a pie piece) using the following code (maybe you'll find something you can use here):

```
OrientSegment = new PathGeometry();
PathFigure figure = new PathFigure();
//Offset is used to convert from clock face radians (starting at top) to system radians (off by 90 degrees, or Tau/4)
double offset = -IRMath.Tau / 4;
Point start = new Point(radius * Math.Cos(minRadians + offset), radius * Math.Sin(minRadians + offset));
Point end = new Point(radius * Math.Cos(minRadians + offset + radianSpan), radius * Math.Sin(minRadians + offset + radianSpan));
figure.StartPoint = new Point(0, 0);
figure.Segments.Add(new LineSegment(start, false));
figure.Segments.Add(new ArcSegment(end, new Size(radius, radius), 0, radianSpan > Math.PI, SweepDirection.Clockwise, true));
figure.Segments.Add(new LineSegment(figure.StartPoint, false));

OrientSegment.Figures.Add(figure);
```

There's just one line of XAML:

```
<Path x:Name="SegmentPath" Data="{Binding OrientSegment, ElementName=root}" Canvas.Left="30" Canvas.Top="30" Fill="{Binding SegmentBrush, ElementName=root}" Stroke="{DynamicResource OrientationSegmentStroke}" StrokeThickness="4"/>
```

Comment: @Moses Aprico Specifically, take a look at the ArcSegment